# Simple form wont post to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Simply lost... I have been looking online for the answer but I cannot see why my code won't post to the MySQL database I have on the WAMP server is have installed locally?
also it doesn't echo the results when I'm trying to test if it is getting anything from the form.

here is my code its a simple form using php to insert it into the database.
the database table has ID (Auto Increment), Fname, Lname, Barcode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<TITLE>Testing Barcode Reader</TITLE>
<style type="text/css">
#body {margin: 0px; }
#pageTop {
height: 90px;
background: grey;
padding: 10px;
}
#pageMiddle {
padding: 20px;
height: 250px;
}
#pageBottom {
padding: 20px;
height: 90px;
}
</style>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$f = $_POST['fname'];
$l = $_POST['Lname'];
$b = $_POST['barcode'];

$db_conx = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysqli_select_db($db_conx,'barcode_test');

$sql = "INSERT INTO barcode (Fname, Lname, Barcode) VALUES ('$f','$l','$b')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
}
?>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<div id="pageTop">
<h1>Testing Barcode Reader</h1>
</div>
<div id="pageMiddle">
<div>

<form action="form.php" method="post">
<div>First Name:</div>
<input name="fname" type="text"  /></br></br>
<div>Last Name:</div>
<input name="Lname" type="text"  /></br></br>
<div>Barcode:</div>
<input name="barcode" type="text"  /></br></br>
<div>Submit Button:</div>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</div>
</div>
<div id="pageBottom">form for testing barcode reader inputs into mysql database</div>
<?php echo($f);
?>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

thanks for any advice you can offer because I'm beginning to believe there is a problem with my WAMP server setup, because even if I copy and paste a simple form from the internet with the database connection settings setup it still wont post or echo?

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Just to be clear, the codes in your question is `form.php`?

Comment: check if `isset($_POST['submit']` Returns true

Comment: And after that make a printout of $sql and try it manually to verify it does what you expect.

Comment: Hi Jen how would I check if it's true?

Comment: Is the above page `form.php`??

Comment: Immediatly after the if line add:
echo 'It is true!';

Comment: ok so I added this code to check if isset is working and nothing echos out on screen.  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 echo "This is set";
}else{ echo "nope"}

Comment: Use view source mode in your browser and search for the output to make sure it's really not there somewhere.

Comment: Hi SpacemanSpiff, I looked at the source code nothing is showing apart from my page code. I also tried debugger and it says no page sources. I viewed this code in dreamweaver and it suggests my code is typed correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `php` even working on your server? The best way to test this is by making a file with this code and this code only in it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If the above doesn't work `php` isn't working correctly on your server.

Also check if you are going to the site by using `localhost/filename.php` or something similar.

Comment: @MichaelFrost Are you going to the site by using localhost and NOT `C://filename//file.php` ?

Comment: i have been using notepad++ and saving the form.php in the www folder of the wamp server and then using the run menu in notepad++ to launch it and run it.

Comment: right I went to the browser as suggested by KittyCat I checked and it is //filename//file.php so I went and changed it to http://localhost/form.php and php seems to be echoing its working now so I just need to find out why its not sending the data to mysql

Comment: got it working thank you so much KittyCat I thought I was losing my mind

Comment: @MichaelFrost No problem, your code was good but for `html` tags please use lowercase.